# Returns zero for all values retrieved from the parse database

Tags: android, parse-platform, cloud, information-retrieval

I'm using parse backend to store and retrieve the datas for my android app, the storing gets done properly but i have problem in retrieving it. I just went through the parse documentation to retrieve the result but what i get is just 0 for all the retrieved values..im suret that the class exists in the parse cloud with valid values but still i get 0 for all the queries.. this is my code to save:

```
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"writing to parse",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ParseObject dataObject = new ParseObject("Score");
    dataObject.put("correct",correctAnswers);
    dataObject.put("wrong",wrongAnswers);
    dataObject.put("percent", percentage);
    dataObject.saveInBackground();
```

this is how i get back the saved data

```
ParseQuery<Score> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Score");
    try {
        List<Score> scoreList = query.find();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Score");
    final Activity ctx = this;
    query.findInBackground( new FindCallback<Score>() {
        @Override public void done(List<Score> scoreList, ParseException e) {
            if ( e == null ) {
                ParseObject dataObject = ParseObject.create("Score");
                int p = dataObject.getInt("correct");
                int q = dataObject.getInt("wrong");
                int r = dataObject.getInt("percent");
                Toast.makeText(ExamRecordActivity.this,String.valueOf(p),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(ExamRecordActivity.this,String.valueOf(q),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(ExamRecordActivity.this,String.valueOf(r),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ctx,
                        "Error updating questions - please make sure you have internet connection",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the done method you are creating a new by calling `ParseObject dataObject = ParseObject.create("Score");` and then trying to read values from it without putting any in.

I don't know what the structure of your class is but you need to be iterating through `List<Score> scoreList` in order to get the queried data.

Comment: Thanks bro, that was the problem... I fixed it